# Connect different data series with the same line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is there a way to get matplotlib to connect data from two different data sets with the same line?

Context: I need to plot some data in log scale, but some of them are negative. I use the workaround of plotting the data absolute value in different colours (red for positive and green for negative), something like:

```
import pylab as pl
pl.plot( x, positive_ys, 'r-' )        # positive y's
pl.plot( x, abs( negative_ys ), 'g-' ) # negative y's
pl.show()
```

However, as they represent the same quantity, it would be helpful to have the two data series connected by the same line. Is this possible?

I cannot use `pl.plot( x, abs( ys ))` because I need to be able to differentiate between the positive and originally negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With numpy you can use logical indexing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.array([10000, 1000, 100, 10, 1, 5, 50, 500, 5000, 50000])
y = np.array([-10000, -1000, -100, -10, -1, 5, 50, 500, 5000, 50000])

ax.plot(x,abs(y),'+-b',label='all data')
ax.plot(abs(x[y<= 0]),abs(y[y<= 0]),'o',markerfacecolor='none', 
                                        markeredgecolor='r', 
                                        label='we are negative')

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

ax.legend(loc=0)

plt.show()
```

The key feature is first plotting all absolute `y`-values and then re-plotting those that were originally negative as hollow circles to single them out. This second step uses the logical indexing `x[y<=0]` and `y[y<=0]` to only pick those elements of the `y`-array which are negative.

The example above gives you this figure:

[image: marked negative]

---

If you really have two different data sets, the following code will give you the same figure as above:

```
x1 = np.array([1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000])
x2 = np.array([5, 50, 500, 5000, 50000])

y1 = np.array([-1, -10, -100, -1000, -10000])
y2 = np.array([5, 50, 500, 5000, 50000])

x = np.concatenate((x1,x2))
y = np.concatenate((y1,y2))

sorted = np.argsort(y)

ax.plot(x[sorted],abs(y[sorted]),'+-b',label='all data')
ax.plot(abs(x[y<= 0]),abs(y[y<= 0]),'o',markerfacecolor='none',
                                        markeredgecolor='r', 
                                        label='we are negative')
```

Here, you first use `np.concatenate` to combine both the `x`- and the `y`-arrays. Then you employ `np.argsort` to sort the `y`-array in a way that makes sure you do not get a overly zig-zaggy line when plotting. You use that index-array (`sorted`) when you call the first plot. As the second plot only plots symbols but no connecting line, you do not require sorted arrays here.